# Need More Verbose MySQL ODBC Error Message

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, odbc

I am using an MS Access form to update a MySQL database via ODBC. The form has three fields that can potentially cause a foreign key constraint violation. When one does, I unsurprisingly get a "[MySQL][ODBC 8.2(a) Driver]Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" error message.

But the error message does not say **which** column caused the violdation! So I am reduced to telling my users that there was a foreign key constraint violation on Field 1 or Field 2 or Field 3. Not ideal!

Is there any way getting ODBC to give me a more verbose error message that would tell me which column caused the error. (Using the ADODB.Errors or DBEngine.Errors collection did not help.) Or some other mechanism that would give me the specifics I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the database produce an error message with the field name to begin with?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are asking. But if I cause a foreign key violation in MySQL Workbench, I get a very verbose error message specifying the column that caused te problem. But in Access, the complete error message I get is as specified in my question.

Comment: Try calling `? Errors(0)`. That works for SQL Server as the backend.

Comment: If you mean calling Errors(0) on my connection string, that does not help. Same (incomplete) error message.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, I recommend you test/find/deal with the error BEFORE the server springs into action.

In other words, in your forms before update event, which will trigger anytime the record is to be updated?

Do the testing at that point, and give a nice user message as to what the issue or problem is. I mean, users don't know about database technology and terms like referential integrity.

So, in the before update event, check that condition.
Example:

```
    Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    
        Dim strWhere        As String ' standard SQL where clause
        
        strWhere = "Hotel_id = " & 123 & " AND Tour_BusID = " & 34343
        
        If DCount("*", "dbo_Tours", strWhere) > 0 Then
        
            MsgBox "Can't update - duplicate tour bus and hotel", vbCritical, "Not allowed"
            
            Cancel = True
            
        End If
        
    
    End Sub
```

Now above is "air code", but simple setup the correct query criteria, and check for the violation, and give a FRIENDLY user message.

If you set cancel = true, then the form close, or record navigation will not occur.

I mean, it is unlikely that you have that many forms where such code can be added. And the code to try and trap the ODBC error not going to be any less messy then above, but the above works, and allows you to deal with the "error" before you lose control of your user interface.

So, code out a nice bit of code that checks in the forms before update event, and thus you give a nice message, and set cancel = true, and thus the ODBC server-side error never gets a chance to run/trigger in the first place.

In other words, you the developer want to separate the concept of a good UI and that of the database system doing its job. I suppose in some cases, attempting to trap the error might work, but often it's too late, and the damage has been done. So, take control of this issue and write a wee bit of code that checks for what would be the error, and give the user a nice friendly message, one about duplicated choices or whatever.

Comment: Except that it's an antipattern that [does not protect you from anything](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071109-00/?p=24553).

Comment: Not really. The issue not having transient information, but that we have known error about to occur - that of saving a record with a invalid key pair value. You can check for this as such, and should check before the database errors. out. As I stated, there is a difference between UI and that of RI. So, in the cases that are "wishey washy" as that article link? Then wishey washy is just that - wishey washy. This use case is not as such.  So, yes, such checking such as not allowing to delete a record that would cause a orphan? Or this case? Yes, you can 99% of the time reliable test this.

Comment: the goal, the task the issue here? Is can code in 99% of cases test what the database engine failure is gong to be? And in this case, you can, and not only can you, but you should.  So, WHEN you can reliable test a use case that will trigger a database engine error? Then yes, you should try to do as such. You can't always achieve this goal, but when you can with relative ease, then you should.  So, out of a 1000 use cases, you might miss what the database engine refuses, and that's still vast better then allowing the database error to trigger, and they often don't bubble up back to the UI well

Comment: Albert, I understand your philosophy and there is a lot to be said for it. And your solution may be the only way. But because it requires three additional round trips to the DB (one for each of my three fields) to test for a condition that will fail most likely infrequently, it is a bit kludgy. Still, it is unfortunate that the ODBC driver returns such a generic and not particularly helpful error message.

Comment: you might be able to build a view that is a join of the 3 fields - it often depends. I mean, either you pre-empt the error and give a nice UI, or try to trap and deal with after the fact. Often say a record delete say can't occur due to say some child records or even a parent record in use. So, I put that code in the UI - the database RI and rules will and can still trigger, but the result is a far better UI.  So, another possible is to call a stored procedure from VBA  - that could again save multiple round trips.